# Turning a Bitmap object into a base64 string having issues

Tags: java, android, base64, encode

I have a simple application where a image is grabbed from the camera, then passed to my onActivityResult() method. I however can't encode the bitmap object into a base64 string. Eclipes tellsi me that the line `byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encode(b, Base64.DEFAULT);` should be a byte[] instead of a String, so this is where i think the issue is (hence the line below it trying to force it as a string object). My code is below, this method gets triggered and the Log appears, but the data is NOT base64.

Can anyone help me please.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch(requestCode){
        case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
            if( resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object   
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); 
                byte[] encodedImage = Base64.encode(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String encodedImageStr = encodedImage.toString();

                Log.e("LOOK", encodedImageStr);


            }
            // RESULT_CANCELED
        break;          
    }               
}
```

Comment: The toString() of a byte[] isn't what you want. Try a encodedImageStr = new String(encodedImage, "UTF-8"); instead.

Comment: The thing is, `Base64.encode(b, Base64.DEFAULT);` should return a String. But eclipes is telling me that the object returned in a byte[]

Comment: use `new String(b);` to create the `encodedImageStr`

Comment: No, you're thinking of Base64#encodeToString() - the method you are using is supposed to return a byte array (which is quite suitable for posting to HTTP servers for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the toString of array object don't do anything with the contents of the array

you should use

```
String encodedImageStr = new String(encodedImage);
```

or you can go directly to String with

```
String encodedImageStr = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: can anyone tell package for Base64 class

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                encode = Base64.encodeBytes(byteArray);
                try {
                    byte[] decode = Base64.decode(encode);
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decode, 0,
                            decode.length);
                    imgview_photo.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                }
```